# Suffering from specific devices killing my home network, mainly mobile devices

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, bandwidth, qos

I'm having some issues with extremely bogged down internet. I've tried several routers with QoS, but they didn't do much.

The internet is plenty fast enough for everything, but the lack of sharing while hog-all programs compete with each other is the problem, leaving no bandwidth left for me to simultaneously do very low bandwidth internet browsing.

Main problems:

1. Mobile phones running backup software at full bore with no throttling options built in (facebook/iCloud/Google Photos/dropbox/etc)
2. Desktop/laptop doing similar backup behavior
3. Streaming movies/netflix
4. Gaming
5. Internet browsing

For 1 and 2, I really don't care how fast they are. I don't want them affecting internet browsing experience, youtube streaming experience, etc.

For 3, the main issue is dealing with 1 and 2. Either always throttle 1 and 2, or throttle when 3 comes on.

For 4 and 5, this is very low bandwidth but needs fast response. Can anyone give advice on configuring either of my routers to prioritize network traffic while someone else is streaming netflix?

I'm thinking the solution involves a router that can either intelligently throttle traffic (if possible? -- seems not 100% possible from experience with QoS routers so far). A simpler solution that would get the job done would be throttling specific devices.

Netgear Nighthawk R6700 is the router I have now.

Comment: Which way did you setup QOS? The defaults in consumer grade routers won't do much. You may have to educate your router on the destination port numbers to prioritize. This should be quite simple to do. and yes, intelligent throttling is achievable depending on what service the router actually uses for QOS. FairQ, priQ, hfsc, cbq etc. Can you add the model numbers of the devices, or whichever device you want to use to accomplish this?

Comment: sure, it's the Netgear Nighthawk R6700. I did try the QoS features for different features like video games as P0, Netflix as P1, and all else P4, but it didn't do anything from what I could tell.

Comment: My Dlink DSL 4320L does QOS priority by device, as you are asking. Their non DSL routers in the same generation probably do the same, but you'd need to check.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart Make the edit and it will go into the reopen queue ..

Comment: Actually I am totally asking for a shopping recommendation as I've followed multiple guides on QoS for this router and the one before it, and nothing has worked. Where would be a better place to ask this? Just googling around, I see tons of similar questions with no good answers. Surely this must be a huge problem for anyone with a family, roommates, or even multiple devices on the same network. How is everyone else solving it? Pointing to a router or two that has QoS that works seems like a perfectly valid solution to my problem to me.

Comment: It's off topic for this forum, QOS works when configured properly. The best I have seen are in this order, Cisco, PFsensr/opensense, DD-WRT/openWRT. For what you are asking, it should work as intended even with a home router. Add a screenshot of the settings to the question. There is a whole other community for hardware recommendations.

Comment: What's the version number of the router? It should be on the underside sticker.